# Tridentine Latin Mass in Hebrew?

Tags: catholicism, church-local, liturgy, hebrew, latin

In 1957, Pope Pius XII gave permission to [St. James Vicariate for Hebrew Speaking Catholics in Israel](https://messianicjewishhistory.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/11-february-bruno-hussar-founds-the-work-of-st-james-neve-shalom-1955-and-issues-statutes-of-the-association-1956/) to celebrate the traditional Tridentine Latin Mass of Pope Pius V in some part in Hebrew.

In Catholicism, the Hebrew and Aramaic languages have always been considered sacred languages from time immemorial.

Can anyone point out to me what parts of the Mass were said in Hebrew and what parts of the Mass were said in Latin? Was Hebrew used in the [Canon of the Mass?](http://www.knight.org/cathen/03255c.htm)

Comment: Pope Pius XII gave permission to this permission  because Hebrew is considered a sacred language the Jewish population in Israel speak Hebrew as an official language!. Besides the Maronite Rite has employed Arabic in their liturgy for centuries.

Answer (score 2):

From the link you gave:

"In February, a report was sent to Cardinal Tisserant. It concluded that the Syrian rite was seen as foreign to many members of the community. The Cardinal referred to the Pope who gave permission to use the Latin rite with some parts of the mass in Hebrew (including the readings)."

So, the Epistle and the Gospel (and the homily) must have been in Hebrew.  But probably not the Canon, otherwise it would not be the Roman Rite. Just a guess.

Comment: Historically speaking, Greek has been used in the Roman Rite in the entirety of the Extraordinary Form of the Mass.